# symfony symlink problem

Tags: unix, symlink

i created a symlink:
`helloises@helloise:/var/www$ sudo ln -s /home/elemental/webroot /var/www/www-rainbowcode-mobi`

when I `ls -lah` this symlink: 
`lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root 23 2011-04-13 15:23 www-rainbowcode-mobi -> /home/elemental/webroot`

is in RED. What does that mean??
And when I stop and start apache2 I get a warning:

> Warning: DocumentRoot
>   [/var/www/www-rainbowcode-mobi] does
>   not exist

can anybody help please??
thank you

Comment: Could you explain what you would like to have as a result?

Answer (score 0):

the color red means that the file you are pointing to does not exist (the apache message tells you so too). Triple check your destination with `ls /home/elemental/webroot`

**UPDATE**

Shouldn't it be something like `/home/helloises/traffic2/elemental/webroot`?

Comment: @Helloise Smit : I'm going to know your computer's filesystem layout by heart ^^